# Login link in menu showing to logged-in user

Tags: 7, navigation

On a Drupal 7 site, I created a login link on the main menu with the path user/login. For some reason, the link remains visible to users that are already logged in. I thought this link is supposed to automatically disappear when a user is logged in.

I also have a logout link that works correctly and only appears to users that are logged in.

Any ideas to get this working correctly?

**EDIT:** I went to /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu and added a new link. In the path field I entered "user/login."

Comment: How did you create the login link? How did you create the logout link? How did you place them on your site?

Comment: I went to /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu and added a new link. In the path field I entered "user/login."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [menu per role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module does exactly like you want. It allows you to set a menu link to only be visible by a specific role, in this case anonymous users.